# How do i order my columns 'Dates' on the basis of a Date

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is  my view that should get ordered by 'weekly holiday' as first
'Annual holiday' as second and 'special holiday' as third and further get ordered according to teh  the column 'Dates' by order of a Date ,that is how a date gets ordered jan,feb ,mar, etc.

```
   Create or Replace view VW_TBL_HOILDAY_APLICATION as    
       SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE A.DESCRIPTION
          WHEN 'Weekly holiday'
          THEN TO_CHAR(A.Holiday_date,'FMDAY')
          WHEN 'Annual holiday'
          THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON')
          WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
          THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON-yy')
        END                                                AS Dates,
        A.DESCRIPTION
        FROM tbl_holiday_master A
        where A.description in('Weekly holiday','Annual holiday','Special_Date_Holiday') 
        order by CASE A.DESCRIPTION
                    WHEN 'Weekly holiday' 
                    THEN '1'
                    WHEN 'Annual holiday'
                    THEN '2'
                    WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
                    THEN '3'
                  END ASC, Dates ASC;
```

but my output is something like this::

```
    DATES   DESCRIPTION
--------------------------    
    SUNDAY  Weekly holiday
    02-OCT  Annual holiday
    15-AUG  Annual holiday
    26-JAN  Annual holiday
    11-NOV-15   Special_Date_Holiday
    25-DEC-15   Special_Date_Holiday
    25-JAN-15   Special_Date_Holiday
```

P.S.:-datatype of my column **dates** in view is varchar because of sunday in it and getting sorted according to a string.
Thanks!.

Comment: Use `order by A.holiday_date` which will sort by the _real_ date value, not the string.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It says it is not a selected expression.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are **converting** the **DATE** into **string**:

```
CASE A.DESCRIPTION
      WHEN 'Weekly holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.Holiday_date,'FMDAY')
      WHEN 'Annual holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON')
      WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON-yy')
END
```

Don't do that in the **view**, but do that whenever you want to **display** the dates while querying the view.

**Create the view as:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TBL_HOILDAY_APLICATION
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT A.holiday_date AS holiday_date,
    A.DESCRIPTION
  FROM tbl_holiday_master A
  WHERE A.description IN('Weekly holiday',
                         'Annual holiday',
                         'Special_Date_Holiday');
```

Then **format** and **sort** the dates while **querying the view**:

```
SELECT
  CASE DESCRIPTION
    WHEN 'Weekly holiday'
    THEN TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'FMDAY')
    WHEN 'Annual holiday'
    THEN TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'dd-MON')
    WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
    THEN TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'dd-MON-yy')
  END AS Dates,
FROM VW_TBL_HOILDAY_APLICATION
ORDER BY holiday_date;
```

Or, if you want to stick to your original view, then the only way is to add the **actual date column** to the **SELECT list** and use it in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TBL_HOILDAY_APLICATION
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE A.DESCRIPTION
      WHEN 'Weekly holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.Holiday_date,'FMDAY')
      WHEN 'Annual holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON')
      WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
      THEN TO_CHAR(A.holiday_date,'dd-MON-yy')
    END AS Dates,
    A.DESCRIPTION,
    A.holiday_date holiday_date
  FROM tbl_holiday_master A
  WHERE A.description IN('Weekly holiday','Annual holiday','Special_Date_Holiday')
  ORDER BY
    CASE A.DESCRIPTION
      WHEN 'Weekly holiday'
      THEN '1'
      WHEN 'Annual holiday'
      THEN '2'
      WHEN 'Special_Date_Holiday'
      THEN '3'
    END ASC,
    holiday_date;
```

Remember, the `ORDER BY` clause at **individual SQL level** always has  **precedence over** the sorting you mentioned in the `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Thanks lalit,your answer is bang on and looks like the only approach left, coz i cannot select holiday_date .:)

Comment: @VishalTyagi Usually I do not prefer sorting within a view, I always leave it at sql level. Anyway, hope it solved your problem. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: i did try your approach but upon addin order by holiday_date while selecting from the view it says not a selected expression.

Comment: @VishalTyagi it was a silly typo, I fixed it. Try now

Comment: Sorry but its not working,says invalid identifier at 'holiday_date'.

Comment: @VishalTyagi When? While creating the view or while querying the view? Can  you create a SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ and show me

Comment: hi @lalit your query works but remember that i needed them as distinct, ,and when i am adding distinct while formatiing the view.it says not a selected expression

Comment: @VishalTyagi Is the view created using my create view code? If yes, then it already is fetching the distinct rows. I am not able to understand when you are getting the error, while creating the view or selecting from it later?

Comment: yes it is the same as yours, it is distinct but when i am substituting those dates as 'Sunday' for weekly holiday then i need it to be distinct.and for annual holiday when dates are suppose 15-aug-14,15-aug-15 and later trimmed to 15-aug and 15-aug then i need distinct dates and  need only one to persist.Sorry if i couldnt explain myslef clearly.@lalit

Comment: @VishalTyagi Then you can add an outer query to select distinct again. Let this entire query be a sub-query. For example, `SELECT DISTINCT dates FROM(SELECT CASE......FROM view)`

Comment: but then the same problem arises,it doesnt get sorted.tried sqlfiddle but was way out of my league..@lalit

Comment: @VishalTyagi Can't you just add the holiday_date, will it affect the distinct? You can still have distinct if you append the holiday_date to your formatted date. You need to compromise at least with the format you want in select or the order of the rows. Choose one.

Comment: this is the exact format that is needed cant do  much about that.Thanks a lot for your help and time.:)@lalit